# Selenium - Java - Unable to click a link

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My problem mainly is that my code doesn't run, I tried for more than 2 hours. I have seen  many posts also, but some are written in different computer languages (not in Java), so I am confused now.

Below is my code for just clicking a button. All I want to do is *click* a button and go to new page.

```
 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
 driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Sanya/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/page%203%20alerts.htm");

 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Alert"));
 element.click();
```

Comment: What is the source code of the button that you are trying to click on?

Comment: can we see the html part?

Comment: <li title="Alerts"><a href="/botnets/botnets" onclick="setTimeout(showLoading, 50);"><span>Alerts</span></a></li>

Comment: That is how the "Alerts" look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below one...

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Alert"))).build().perform();
```

It was worked for me :-)

Comment: Hey! I have been getting "Obsolute method on stack" error. Would you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I had used the same code you provided me. Ill update my question

Comment: I gave the information in the question, if you got ANY idea please help me out, I have tried over 6 hours now.

Comment: Try with xpath //li[@title='Alerts']/a/span

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works fine for me:

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("your_id"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath for instance to locate the element on your page:

```
By locator = By.xpath("//li[@title='Alerts']/a");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
```

[Here](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html) is more information about how XPath works.